# Only return objects that pass boolean?

Tags: javascript, object, boolean

```
AppUser.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('error')
    } else {

        for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++){
            users[i].connected
        }

        res.json(users);
    }
});
```

I only want to set my res json to show objects that have `connected` set to true.

I feel so dumb not knowing how to do this, but there has to be a simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the `users` who are `connected`, like this

```
users = users.filter(function(currentUser) {
    return currentUser.connected;
});
```

Now, `users` will have an array of user information which have a Truthy `connected`.

Comment: ok looks good let me try it. Sure it works will give you props in a second :)

Comment: I need to learn more javascript because just when I though I was good I couldn't even do something this simple. Thanks it works!!

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Please go through [Array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Object Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). They will come in handy often :)